# Is this a possibility , that interface Inheritance from Class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, comparator

I have been studying interface comparator and I heard that the equals method is inherited from the Object class.

How it's possible? Isn't it that an interface can only inherit from another interface?

Comment: Well, all classes that *implement* an interface necessarily extend `Object` (directly or indirectly), and thus have an `equals` method.

Comment: okey, but why in Comparator we have a equals method?

Comment: Because all classes that implement `Comparator` extend `Object` directly or indirectly. Or, to put it another way, there's no way to implement `Comparator` in a way such that it doesn't have an `equals` method.

Comment: If you're alluding to asking why `equals` appears in the Javadoc for `Comparator` but other methods inherited from `Object` (e.g. `toString`) don't, it's because there is something more specific to say about the `equals` method than just the plain `Object.equals` method's documentation says.

Comment: The Comparator interface specifies `equals` so that it can override the JavaDoc with additional comments specific to classes which implement it. There is no other reason, nor any magic going on. It is purely declared to provide the opportunity for the authors to add additional documentation.

Answer (score 2):

All classes that implement an interface necessarily extend Object (directly or indirectly), and thus have an equals method.

Methods are overridden in interfaces purely for documentation purposes, such as this, to allow additional constraints (or more detailed information) to be provided for implemetations of the interface.

The significant part of the Javadoc for [`Comparator.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is:

> This method must obey the general contract of `Object.equals(Object)`. Additionally, this method can return true only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator.

So, this is saying that implementations of `Comparator.equals` give stronger guarantees than the more general `Object.equals` method: that if this method says two things are equal, then they *must* order objects in the same way.

---

With that said, I have never knowingly seen a `Comparator` implementation which does override `equals`. After all, this is just a thing which does comparisons - how often do you need to compare such a thing to another?

The only situation I can think where it would be useful is if you were building a `List<Comparator<Something>>`, and didn't want to have more than one comparator which imposes the same ordering. Shrug - perhaps this is just a failure of my imagination to think of something more useful.

Comment: but that means that the class that extends the interface inherits from the object class, not the interface

Comment: A class which implements `Comparator` is an instance of *both* `Comparator` and `Object` (or whatever class it directly extends). Its `equals` method has to satisfy the contract of both `Object.equals` (/`DirectSuperclass.equals`) and `Comparator.equals`.

Comment: "*The only situation I can think*"... Maybe one reasonable hypothetical would be some UI table which allows the user to sort by individual columns. If they tried to apply a sort which was already applied, it might be a useful optimization to check whether the two comparators for the table were the same before potentially redrawing everything.

Comment: [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) overrides `equals`. It did so even before the `Comparator` interface was created.

Answer (score 1):

By default equals method is inherited from Object class which is a parent of all classes.
Default equals method works as == operator. It compares the object references if they refer to the same object in memory